# I need Newtonsoft JSON deserialization to skip an entry in a given dictionary JSON

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net, deserialization

I have this class as my JSON schema (is that the right term?):

```cs
class BasicInfoDatabase : Dictionary<string, BasicInfo>,
    IDictionary<string, BasicInfo>, 
    ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, BasicInfo>>, 
    IDictionary, 
    ICollection,
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, BasicInfo>, 
    IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<string, BasicInfo>>,
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, BasicInfo>>, 
    IEnumerable, 
    ISerializable, 
    IDeserializationCallback 
{ }
```

*Note: All of `Dictionary`'s interfaces are specified here to solve unrelated errors. Otherwise, I'd omit them.*

There's an entry in the input JSON string that isn't formatted as a `BasicInfo` object. I'd like to ignore that specific entry when deserializing the input string. This is the code I'm using for this use:

```cs
private static bool HandleInfoReceipt( string jsonStr, out BasicInfoDatabase infoDb ) {
    infoDb = new BasicInfoDatabase();

    JObject respJson = JObject.Parse( jsonStr );
    if( respJson.Count == 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    infoDb = respJson.ToObject<BasicInfoDatabase>();
    if( infoDb == null ) {
        throw new NullReferenceException( "No info found" );
    }

    return true;
}
```

How do I skip that entry?

Comment: Have you tried [JsonIgnore] attribute (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm)?

Comment: read the respone to a jObject, and and manually traverse the properties, and then just ignore the property that you want.

Comment: [JsonIgnore] doesn't apply for dictionary keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward to filter out properties from a `JObject`.  How you do it depends on what you know about the JSON and what you don't.

For example, let's say that your `BasicInfo` class is defined like this:

```
class BasicInfo
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And your JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "good": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Foo",
    "Amount": 14.95
  },
  "acceptable": {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Bar"
  },
  "suspect": {
    "Id": 3,
    "Hmm": "Blah"
  },
  "bad": {
    "Foo": "Bar",
    "Baz": "Quux"
  },
  "ugly": "total garbage"
}
```

If you know the specific keys that are causing problems, you could make a simple extension method to filter those out, like this:

```
public static void FilterOutUnwantedProperties(this JObject jo, params string[] keys)
{
    var unwantedProperties = jo.Properties().Where(jp => keys.Contains(jp.Name)).ToList();

    foreach (JProperty prop in unwantedProperties)
    {
        prop.Remove();
    }
}
```

Then, call it from your `HandleInfoReceipt` method like this:

```
respJson.FilterOutUnwantedProperties("bad", "ugly");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TfH6Fr

---

On the other hand, maybe you don't know the keys ahead of time, or they are dynamic.  Perhaps a better approach is to make the extension method check that each property value in the JObject is actually an object itself and check the names of the *child* object properties to ensure that at least one of them (or all of them?) match your desired item type.  That might look something like this:

```
public static void FilterOutPropertiesThatAreNotCompatibleWith<TItem>(this JObject jo, BindingFlags flags=BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance)
{
    var knownItemPropertyNames = 
        typeof(TItem).GetProperties(flags)
                     .Select(p => p.Name);
    var knownItemFieldNames = 
        typeof(TItem).GetFields(flags)
                     .Select(p => p.Name);
    var knownItemMemberNames = new HashSet<string>(knownItemPropertyNames);
    knownItemMemberNames.UnionWith(knownItemFieldNames);

    var unwantedProperties = 
        jo.Properties()
          .Where(jp => jp.Value.Type != JTokenType.Object ||
                       !jp.Value.Children<JProperty>()
                                .Any(cp => knownItemMemberNames.Contains(cp.Name)))
          .ToList();

    foreach (JProperty prop in unwantedProperties)
    {
        prop.Remove();
    }
}
```

You would call this version like this:

```
respJson.FilterOutPropertiesThatAreNotCompatibleWith<BasicInfo>();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WsDmCE

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
 var result = new BasicInfoDatabase();
 var jObject = JObject.Parse( jsonStr );
 foreach (var kvp in jObject )
 {
     if(kvp.Key != "<property-you-want-to-skip>")
     {
         result.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToObject<BasicInfo>());
     }  
 }
```

**EDIT**

More like this:

```
kvp.Value.ToObject<BasicInfo>();
```

Comment: Do you mean ```cs
 result.Add(kvp.Key, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BasicInfo>(kvp.Value.ToString()));
```
?